# :via => [:options] in ruby on rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In some Rails app, I saw this in the routes.rb

```
root :to => "home#index", :via => [:get]
root :to => "accounts#manage", :via => [:options]
```

I could not understand how these two root URLs can exist. Googling didn't help clear the :options argument either. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2) (and explained a bit more [here](http://zacstewart.github.io/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html)), there is an OPTIONS verb - which routes can support.

The impetus for using OPTIONS is to request documentation for a web service API; results are meant to provide information regarding how the API may be used.

```
ActionDispatch::Routing::HTTP_METHODS
=> [:get, :head, :post, :put, :delete, :options]
```

To get back to your question, in a typical browser GET request, the first route will be used.  When an OPTIONS request is made, the second route will be used.

Comment: Example which matches any http verb: `match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all`, from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :via option to constrain the request to one or more HTTP methods

See [the rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)

`:post`, `:get`, `:put`, `:delete`, `:options`, `:head`, and `:any` are allowed as a value to this option.

As explained in [a blog post](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428), OPTIONS is just another HTTP verb to support [CORS requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control) (a way to make cross domain AJAX requests).

**Update** found a blog post explaining `:options`

Comment: In fact the magic keyword is not `:any`, its `:all`. `match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all`, from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5 and above:
in routes.rb

```
  match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found", via:  :all
  match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_server_error", via: :all
```

For controller:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'xyz'
  def not_found
  end

  def internal_server_error
  end
end
```

This will work in production, if you want the same for the development also, then in development.rb
change:

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```